# Vue: How to find the closest higher and lower value in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I am currently working on a Vue.js application. I have a specified value, and I need to find the closest higher value and the closest lower value compared to it. But how do I do it, inside a Vue function?

This is just a part of the code, as much as needed to describe the problem. The actual problems are located in the second computed function under "new Vue".

At first, I am sorting the array with an orderedByPosition function. After that, I am trying to identify the two values that I need. And now, the problems begin... A part of the problems is the message:
*"[Vue warn]: Getter is missing for computed property "computed"*. That I get in the Chrome browser console.

**HTML**

```
<div id="results">
  {{ higher }} {{ subject }} {{ lower }}
</div>
```

**Vue.js**

```
let subject;
let number;
let closest;
let higherValue;
let lowerValue
let you = [];
let cArray = [];

dummyList = [{
       goals: 42,
  },
  {
        goals: 20,
  },
  {
        goals: 15,
  },
  {
        goals: 5,
  }
];

subject = 16;

Vue.component('Donegoals', {

  data: function() {
    return {
      higher: higherValue,
      subject: subject,
      lower: lowerValue
    }
  }
});
new Vue({
  el: '#results',
  data: {
    cArray: dummyList
  },
  computed: {
    orderedByPosition: function() {
      return _.sortBy(this.cArray, 'goals')
    },
    computed: {  // Here is the function that is not working correctly
      closest: function(closest) {
        closest = this.cArray.sort((a, b) => Math.abs(subject - a) - Math.abs(subject - b))[0];

        if (closest > subject || closest === subject) {
          higherValue = closest
        } else {
          lowerValue = closest
        }
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: `computed` can only hold functions. You have a second entry `computed` in your code as a child property of the `computed` section of your vm. If that is intentional, it's a) a really bad idea to give it the name `computed` and b) it has to be a `Function`, not a non-function `Object`.

Comment: @connexo [it *could* be an object](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/WzjLRw?editors=1010), but one of the properties would have to be a get function. Completely agree with everything else.

Comment: How am I applying this to the code?

Comment: Something like this. https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/JLNzmr?editors=1010

Comment: @Ben! A very neat solution! I got a little problem with the output. I use a template for the HTML and the tags don't get updated in the same way!